# Not able to create test case using java rally rest api

Tags: java, web-services, rest, rally

When i try to create the test case using rally api it isn't working, it gives an error,

Could not read: Object not found for Object ID: null

But when i try to query it, it works.

below is the code snippet,

```
public class App {
    public static void main( String[] args ){

        String host = "https://rally1.rallydev.com/";
        String wsapiVersion = "v2.0";
        String projectRef = "/project/test";
        String applicationName = "Rally test";
        String myWorkspace = "/workspace/myWorkspace";
        RallyRestApi restApi = new RallyRestApi(new URI(host),"my api key");
        restApi.setApplicationName(applicationName);
        restApi.setApplicationVersion(wsapiVersion);
        String e = "proxy URL";
        String user = "username";
        String pwd = "pass";
        restApi.setProxy(new URI(e), user, pwd);

        JsonObject newTestCase = new JsonObject();
         newTestCase.addProperty("Project", projectRef);
         newTestCase.addProperty("Name", "Rally test");
         CreateRequest createRequest = new CreateRequest("testcase",newTestCase);
         CreateResponse createResponse = restApi.create(createRequest);
         if (createResponse.wasSuccessful()){
             System.out.println("Test case created successfully");
             }
             else {
             System.out.println("The test case could not be created");
             String[] createErrors;
             createErrors = createResponse.getErrors();
             System.out.println("Error occurred creating Test Case: ");
             for (int i=0; i<createErrors.length;i++) {
                System.out.println(createErrors[i]);
            }
             }



        QueryRequest request = new QueryRequest("User");
        request.setFetch(new Fetch(new String[] { "UserName" }));
        request.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("UserName","=", "rally user"));
        QueryResponse response = restApi.query(request);
        if (response.getTotalResultCount() > 0) {
            JsonObject userObject = response.getResults().get(0).getAsJsonObject();
            String ref = Ref.getRelativeRef(userObject.get("_ref").getAsString());
            System.out.println("hweouhowhochwoiiceihh"+ref);
        }

        QueryRequest subscriptionRequest = new QueryRequest("Subscriptions");
        QueryResponse subscriptionQueryResponse = restApi.query(subscriptionRequest);

        String subName = subscriptionQueryResponse.getResults().get(0).getAsJsonObject().get("Name").toString();
        System.out.println("Read Subscription: " + subName);

        QueryRequest workspaceRequest1 = new QueryRequest(subscriptionQueryResponse.getResults().get(0).getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonObject("Workspaces"));
        workspaceRequest1.setFetch(new Fetch("Name", "_ref"));

        JsonArray myWorkspaces = restApi.query(workspaceRequest1).getResults();

        //Iterate through the Workspaces to find the correct one
        String workspaceName = "";
        String Wspace_ref;
        for (int i=0; i<myWorkspaces.size(); i++){
            workspaceName = myWorkspaces.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("Name").getAsString();
            System.out.printf("Workspace found ==> %s\n", workspaceName);
            Wspace_ref = myWorkspaces.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("_ref").getAsString();
            System.out.println("Wspace_ref "+Wspace_ref);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: In your real code is projectRef something more like "/project/12345"?  That's the only thing that looks strange to me...

Comment: I tried with /project/projectID which is part of rally url https://rally1.rallydev.com/#/projectID  and it worked, earlier i was trying with name.